# How to implement OOP in Kivy

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I can't understand how to change screen in Kivy that's locate in another py file. I have the **main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from screen_1 import Screen1
from screen_3 import Screen3


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


sm = WindowManager()

screens = [Screen1(name="Screen1"), Screen3(name="Screen3")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "Screen1"


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and have two py-files with the screens:

**screen_1.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

screen = '''

ScreenManagement:

    Screen1:
        name: 'screen1'
        id: screen1        
    Screen2:
        name: 'screen2'
        id: screen2


<Screen1>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Screen 1'
            text_color: 'black'            
        Button:
            text: 'Screen_2'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .3}
            on_press:
                root.change_screen()

<Screen2>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Screen 2'
            text_color: 'black'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        Button:
            text: 'Screen_3'            
            on_press:
                root.change_screen_3()
        Button:            
            text: 'BackToScreen_1'                
            on_press:
                root.change_screen_1()

'''


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Screen1(Screen):

    def change_screen(self):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'


class Screen2(Screen):

    def change_screen_1(self):
        self.manager.current = 'screen1'
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'

    def change_screen_3(self):

        self.manager.current = 'Screen3'
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'left'


class App(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(screen)


App().run()
```

**screen_3.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

screen3 = '''

ScreenManagement:

    Screen3:
        name: 'screen3'
        id: screen3        



<Screen3>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Screen 3'
            text_color: 'black'            
        Button:
            text: 'ToScreen_2'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .3}
            on_press:
                root.change_screen()

'''


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Screen3(Screen):

    def change_screen(self):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'


class App(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(screen3)


App().run()
```

The problem is that when I start from **main.py** and click on the button 'Screen3' (see **screen_1.py**), the screen does not change - app is crashed. But when i've tried to import 'screen3' from **screen_3.py** to **screen_1.py** the app loaded only 'screen3' not 'screen1'. What am I doing wrong and what is necessary for the screens to change

Comment: as for me your code makes no sense. Program should run only one `App().run()` and use only one `ScreenManager`. You should remove `App().run()` from imported files because it runs it automatically when you import it - or you should keep `App().run()` in `if __name__ == '__main__':` and it will skip this code when you import it. And I'm not sure if `kv` strings can be in as 3 separated elements. In current code you try to run 3 separated programs - and they can't have access one with other.

Comment: I agree with you. After reviewing many examples and guides, I tried to create my own version of the OOP application, but I know that it was executed crookedly. I didn't have enough knowledge to structure the code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a number of different ways to break code up across files here is an example:

main.py

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from screen_one import ScreenOne  # these imports load the kv
from screen_two import ScreenTwo

kv = """
ScreenManager:  # root widget
    ScreenOne:
        name: 'one'
    ScreenTwo:
        name: 'two'
"""


class MyScreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyScreensApp().run()
```

screen_one.py

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

kv = """
<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'Screen One'
    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(48)
        text: 'Next Screen'
        on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.next()
"""
Builder.load_string(kv)


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # you could declare an App here and put standalone test code
    from kivy.app import App

    class TestThisScreen(App):
        def build(self):
            return ScreenOne()

    TestThisScreen().run()
```

screen_two.py

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

kv = """
<ScreenTwo>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: .5, .7, .5
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos:self.pos
    Label:
        text: 'Screen Two'
    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(48)
        text: 'Next Screen'
        on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.next()
"""
Builder.load_string(kv)


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass
```

This is a minimal example. Typically there would be some code associated with each Screen class.  Combining the python and kv code together like this can simplify file management.  The downside is you don't get the benefit of syntax highlighting of the kv.  You can do something similar and put the kv in separate files.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind man! Your help has helped me a lot. And are there any resources with examples where I could look at examples of changing screens using OOP (in addition to the Kivy manual and YouTube)

Comment: There is a example in the kivy-examples directory.  You can find that under your venv.   Look: venv/share/kivy-examples/widgets/screenmanager.py  The screen is changed with the "current" attribute of the ScreenManager is changed to a different Screen name.